# Side navigation bar (menu) (iOS 6) like in Facebook app + storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios6, storyboard

I want to create side menu like in Facebook iPhone app in iOS 6 using Xcode and Storyboards.
How can I make it?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to make it from code, not using storyboards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get custom component like Inferis/ViewDeck and implement containment programmatically:

```
@interface YourViewController : IIViewDeckController

@end
```

implementation:

```
@implementation YourViewController

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
  UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
  self.centerController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CenterViewController"];
  self.leftController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
}

@end
```

Comment: there is an example in repo, get and study it https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

Comment: this example uses .xib files, I know how to make it with xib. I'd like to use storyboards

Comment: sorry but what should i do with left and center controller afterwards cause i have no clue

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab I don't understand you, please specify your problem.

Comment: @egor.zhdan can you tell me how to use sidebar menu using swift in xib??
OR
How to use it using objective c in xib with the help of bridge-header.
please tell me thanks in advance....

Comment: @sohanvanani No, I've never tried to make it since iOS 7 release, because Apple doesn't recommend to make sidebar menus now.

Answer (score 7):

We wrote MMDrawerController to solve this problem, but I havent thought about using it in a storyboard (simply because storyboards aren't maintainable for large teams).

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: Definitely recommend this one. Best implementation of "slide-out" navigation I've ever seen.
@KCHarwood thanks for your hard work, guys ;)

Comment: A very cool implementation indeed! Almost makes you want to make a new app just to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else would like to do something similar.. I've succeeded using ECSlidingView. It is already done using storyboards. There's also an example included.

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController.git

EDIT:

Well after implementing this ECSlidingViewController i see that the navigation is slow, and strange. Switched to IIViewDeckController after all. Fast and easy, super!